# IPython %store magic not persisting

Tags: python, alias, ipython, ipython-magic

I'm trying to get an IPython alias to persist, and according to [docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html) the `%store` magic offers this feature. But it's not working:

```
$ echo 'print("hello world!")' > test.py
$ ipython
In [1]: alias potato python /tmp/test.py

In [2]: potato
hello world!

In [3]: %store potato
Alias stored: potato (python /tmp/test.py)

In [4]: 
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? 
$ ipython
In [1]: potato
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e561f9248d75> in <module>()
----> 1 potato

NameError: name 'potato' is not defined
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to run [`%store -r`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/0ca701d56a2d12074b725d3fd99cacc30c5c62cb/IPython/extensions/storemagic.py#L106) to retrieve stored variables (and aliases).

Of course, you can add this to your ipython startup script.

Comment: OK.  For ubuntu 13.10, it worked by adding my magic into `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/startup/wim.ipy`

Comment: Thanks @wim, didn't know about the possibility to even use startup ipy-files (only knew to use normal python files), but this makes it very easy for me as the `store -r` doesnt work for me somehow

Comment: It is possible to automatically store all variable in ipython?

Answer (score 1):

You can also restore in a regular script, for instance if your IDE (Spyder) doesn't support the `ipython_config.py` file:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.magic("store -r")
```

(Put this in a file that's called in the Startup tab of Spyder's IPython configuration.  This took me way too long to figure out.)

Answer (score 0):

@ecatmur's solution worked for me. Thanks! I want only add an example how to add a startup script.
Just add .ipy file to `.ipython/profile_default/startup/` directory with following content `%store -r`:

```
[ikors@localhost ~]$ cat .ipython/profile_default/startup/startup_script.ipy
%store -r
```